# openerp Message_post error..NameError: global name '_' is not defined

Tags: python, odoo

I have created a custom module with chatter in the form.

I want to post a custom message. but I am getting following error.

```
File "/opt/openerp/my_modules/forum/forum.py", line 22, in function_which_post_msg
    self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, body=_("New Question has been <b>created</b>"), context=context)
NameError: global name '_' is not defined
```

my .py file is

```
import datetime
import time
import openerp
from openerp.osv import osv, fields


class Course(osv.osv):
    _name = "forum.course"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

    _columns = {
              'name' : fields.char(string="Question Title", size=256, required=True),
              'description' : fields.text(string="Question Description", required=True),

               }


    def function_which_post_msg(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, body=_("New Question has been <b>created</b>"), context=context)

    def create(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        self.function_which_post_msg(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this to import in your .py file

**from openerp import tools**

**from openerp.tools.translate import _**

**_** is used for a translation the message when active user's language is changed according to. It's translate the message as in your **.po** file.

Comment: _ error is solved but, getting following error.


File "/opt/openerp/my_modules/forum_nyros/forum.py", line 24, in function_which_post_msg
    self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, body=_("New Question has been <b>created</b>"), context=context)
  File "/opt/openerp/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 1023, in message_post
    "Invalid thread_id; should be 0, False, an ID or a list with one ID"

Comment: can you please make a new question? so don't overlap this question title. And Accept this answer. Thanks

Comment: I posted as new question, plz check it and help me

Comment: my new question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673290/openrerp-chatter-message-post-error