# Openrerp chatter message_post error

Tags: python, odoo

I have created a custom module with chatter in the form.

I want to post a custom message. but I am getting following error.

```
  File "/opt/openerp/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 1023, in message_post
    "Invalid thread_id; should be 0, False, an ID or a list with one ID"
AssertionError: Invalid thread_id; should be 0, False, an ID or a list with one ID
```

For my .py  program is at the following link

http://pastebin.com/9Bq4MZQ9

Comment: Does your stack trace show which line in _your_ code is triggering the error?

Comment: its showing error is in line 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function, Hope this will solve your error.

```
def function_which_post_msg(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):     
    self.message_post(cr, uid, [ids[0]], body=_("New Question has been <b>created</b>"), context=context)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, great job, You helping me a lot to learn OpenERP. Keep It up, Thank you.