# "global name '_' is not defined" during raising ValidationError

Tags: python, django, validationerror

I'm following [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror) about raising `ValidationError` in Django.

Unfortunatelly even the simplest snippet won't work. I've added below code to my validator object:

```
raise ValidationError(_('Invalid value'), code='invalid')
```

and got error

> global name '_' is not defined

What did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [openerp Message\_post error..NameError: global name '\_' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671417/openerp-message-post-error-nameerror-global-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: Forgot: `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing this line:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Answer (score 1):

For Django 3+ this has changed to:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

The documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/)